# Empty Redux store when attempting to dispatch from outside React component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have what I think is a fairly standard React-Redux setup with some persistence mixed in.

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import config from 'cgConfig';

const { store, persistor } = configureStore();

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <AppRouter />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById(config.constants.element.rootId));
```

configureStore.js

```
import {
    createStore,
    combineReducers
} from 'redux';
import {
    persistStore,
    persistReducer
} from 'redux-persist';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

import config from 'cgConfig';

//...import reducers...

export default () => {
    const persistConfig = {
        key: 'root',
        storage,
        stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
    };

    let rootReducer = combineReducers({
        //...all of my reducers...
    });

    let store = undefined;
    let pr = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

    if (config.env.includeReduxDevTools) {
        store = createStore(
            pr,
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
        );
    } else {
        store = createStore(pr);
    }

    let persistor = persistStore(store);

    return {
        store,
        persistor
    };
};
```

However, the one thing that is a bit unconventional is that I need to update the store outside the context of a react component. As far as I understand ([for example](https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/)), this should not be too difficult to accomplish. Simply call `configureStore()` to get the store and run a `store.dispatch(action)`. Problem is that I keep getting the initial state of the store back (IE empty), which isn't the same as the one I have already set up through the process of logging in etc. Thus when I run a `dispatch`, the wrong state is being updated.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, would appreciate any help.

EDIT to answer Uma's question about what the router looks like:

First some more context. The website I am working on will basically have shapes generated in something akin to a graph. These shapes can be manipulated after they are selected from various sources like contextual menus and a toolbar. It is in the context of this change event that I am working on.

When a change is made, the info of the selected item and what needs to be changed will be sent to a generic function which will determine which reducer/action to use to update the Redux store. All my reducers follow the same pattern and look like this:

```
const reducerInitialState = {};

const setSomeProperty= (state, action) => {
    let newState = { ...state };

    newState.some_property = action.some_update;

    return newState;
};

export default (state = reducerInitialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_SOME_PROPERTY':
            return setSomeProperty(state, action);
        case 'LOG_OUT':
            return { ...reducerInitialState };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Action for completeness:

```
export const setSomeProperty = update_data => ({
    type: 'UPDATE_SOME_PROPERTY',
    some_update: update_data
});
```

The generic function I have would look something like this:

```
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import { setSomeProperty} from './actions/SomeAction';
import API from './utilities/API';

export default async ({ newValue, selectedShape }) => {
    if (!newValue || !selectedShape)
        throw "Cannot update the server with missing parameters.";

    await API()
        .post(
            `/api/update-shape`,
            {
                newValue,
                shape: selectedShape
            }
        )
        .then(response => {
            updateValue({ selectedShape, newValue });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // handle error
        });
}

const getAction = ({ shape }) => {
    switch (shape.type) {
        case 0:
            return setSomeProperty;
        default:
            throw `Invalid type of ${shape.type} attempting to update.`;
    }
}

const updateValue = ({ selectedShape, newValue }) => {
    const action = getAction({ shape: selectedShape })
    const { store } = configureStore();
    store.dispatch(action(newValue))
}
```

Note: API is a wrapper for Axios.

Since posting this yesterday I have read that creating a second store like what I am doing with `const { store } = configureStore();` is where one of my problems lie in that React/Redux can't have 2 of them. I have also come to realize that the problem most likely have to do with the initial state in my reducers, that somehow using `configureStore()` does not send the actual state to the reducers and thus all my reducers are showing their initial states when I look at them using `console.log(store.getState());`. If this is true, at least I know the problem and that is half the battle, but I am unsure how to proceed as I have tried to ReHydrate the state I get from `configureStore()` but nothing seems to work the way I expect it to.

Comment: how does the reducer looks like for `store.dispatch(action)` that needs to update you store?

Comment: Hi @Uma. I've posted an update as you requested.

Comment: thanks, that's helpful. In your reducer I might be missing something but I do not see where you actually set any data for `'UPDATE_SOME_PROPERTY'`, you only have `'SET_SOME_ATTRIBUTES'` and `LOG_OUT`

Comment: also I usually get dispatch in different way `import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';` and then in component `const dispatch = useDispatch(); dispatch(youAction(value));` not sure if that makes difference since I haven't  gone the route you did it

Comment: my bad, I'll update `'SET_SOME_ATTRIBUTES'` to `'UPDATE_SOME_PROPERTY'`. Copy paste error. I'll investigate the `useDispatch` function. I wasn't aware of its existence. The way in which I would normally use dispatch is within the context of the React Component where I will have access to `this.props.dispatch(...);`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you end up in a weird loop where you call an action `setSomeProperty` then it gets you to the reducer, and in reducer you call that `setSomeProperty` action again.

In reducer I would expect to see something like this:

```
export default (state = reducerInitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_SOME_PROPERTY':
          return {
            ...state, // preserve already set state properties if needed
            some_update: action.some_update
          }
      case 'LOG_OUT':
          return { ...reducerInitialState };
      default:
          return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: The problem isn't really that I can't update the Redux store, it's that I would like to update it from outside the context of a React Component. A temporary solution that I have found is to pass the `dispatch` function to generic function as a callback. Using the callback I can successfully update the store and change reflects on the page. What I would like is to be able to access dispatch without needing to pass it as a callback. Doing the callback method tightly couples my generic function to React Components and I would ideally like to avoid that.